# combine two arrays and create a third array using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have 2 arrays, say `arr1=[A,B,C,D];`
and arr2= `[a,b,c,d];`
I want to create a third array by combining these 2 in the following way:

```
arr3= [A,a,B,b,C,c,D,d];
```

How can I achieve this using jquery? Please help!

Comment: Define exactly how you're ordering the elements in the final array. Alphabetical, or do you just want to alternate between arr1 and arr2?

Comment: Just want to alternate between arr1 and arr2. In exact way as shown in the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to use jquery's [`$.merge(array1,array2)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/) function,

```
var arr3 = $.merge( arr1, arr2 )
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EWDt2/)

For the format you have asked,

```
var arr1=['A','B','C','D'];
var arr2=['a','b','c','d'];

var arr3 = [];

for(var i=0,len=arr1.length;i<len;i++){
    arr3[arr3.length] = arr1[i];
    arr3[arr3.length] = arr2[i];
}

alert(arr3);
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/EWDt2/1/)

Comment: This won't put it in the order shown in the question.

Comment: Note that, according to the docs, `arr1` will be altered by this operation.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yeah, that's true. but op just asked how to combine two arrays.

Comment: He *did* ask for it to be in a certain format, though.

Comment: @RocketHazmat answered. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to alternate elements between the two arrays, and that they're always equal in length:

```
arr3 = [];
for (var i=0,j=arr1.length; i<j; i++) {
    arr3.push(arr1[i]);
    arr3.push(arr2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one string by using `merge` function.
The new array will be returned without altering merged arrays:

```
var arr3 = $.merge($.merge([], arr1), arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will interleave two arrays of any length, and return the result. No jquery required.

```
function interleave(a,b) {
    c=[];
    tot=a.length+b.length;
    while (c.length<tot) {
        if (aa=a.shift()) {
            c.push(aa);
        }
        if (bb=b.shift()) {
            c.push(bb);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

If you want to merge two arrays and sort alphabetically, try this (also no jquery)

```
arr3=arr1.concat(arr2).sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.merge function as

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arr1=['a','b'];
  var arr2=['c','d'];
  console.log($.merge(arr1,arr2));  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/850274/

Answer (score 0):

You can interleave two arrays using the recursive function below. This method will work whether or not the arrays are the same length:

```js
var z = (a, b) => a.length ? [a[0], ...z(b, a.slice(1))] : b;

var arr1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var arr2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

var arr3 = z(arr1, arr2);
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));
```

or for any number of arrays, use this:

```js
var z = (a = [], ...b) => 
    b.length ? a.length ? [a[0], ...z(...b, a.slice(1))] : z(...b) : a;

var array1 = [1, 2];
var array2 = '♦♡♣♤♥♢';
var array3 = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var array4 = ['', '', ''];
var array5 = [null, NaN, undefined];

var stringify = (o) => JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => v === undefined ? '__undefined__' : v !== v ? '__NaN__' : v).replace(/"__undefined__"/g, 'undefined').replace(/"__NaN__"/g, 'NaN');

console.log(stringify(z()));
console.log(stringify(z(array1)));
console.log(stringify(z(array1, array2)));
console.log(stringify(z(array1, array2, array3)));
console.log(stringify(z(array1, array2, array3, array4)));
console.log(stringify(z(array1, array2, array3, array4, array5)));
```